# How to Stop Session goes to Negative Value?

Tags: php, session

In this Code Remove case Perform More and More time than Session Get Negative value.which type of changes are occuring in code for Session get Only Positive value.

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $d1=$_POST['d1'];
    $action=$_POST['str1'];
    $product_id = $_POST['productid'];
    switch($action) 
    { 
    case "Add":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = $d1 + (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]) ?$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] : 0);
    break;
        case "Remove":
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]=(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]) ? $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] : 0)- $d1;
            if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] == 0)
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]); 
            break;
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: thx Fred-ii- and Please help me in main Logic

Comment: That `+` sign you have in there, I'm not sure that's valid. Try using `&&` instead. Or is that used for calculations?

Comment: + sign working.. and all code working.. when remove case perform more time than session get negative value..this main concept

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with it, sorry.

Comment: when remove case perform more times than session['cart'] value goes to -5,-6 so on...how to i stop

Comment: I don't know, sorry. As I said earlier, I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<=` instead of `==` to avoid negative values

```
if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] <= 0)
```

Also you're missing the `break;` statement from the "Add" case

Answer (score 0):

in case of "Remove": section.

you first count the list of items and place the if else check if count > 0 then perform remove operation else

skip the removal.